# Clean up [translate] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) tag is being used for a variety of unrelated concepts (text language translation, the graphics movement operation, converting programs from one programming language to another) by 600+ questions. It should be killed and/or split into separate meaningful tags.